# Silverlight Binding with/without the "Path=" syntax

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

When is the "Path=" xaml syntax required when specifying a binding to a property?
I see this "Path=" pretty much exclusively when there is a nested property binding (ex: Path=Person.FirstName).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like initializing a class in C#. If the "Binding" class has a constructor that takes a path, you could do this:

```
new Binding("Person.FirstName");
```

... or this:

```
new Binding { Path = "Person.FirstName" };
```

The two are the same, for all intents and purposes. XAML is doing the same thing. If you omit the "Path=" you're passing a path into the constructor for Binding, but if you include it you're setting the value after the fact.

I often leave the "Path=" out, especially if I'm declaring a binding with no other properties set, like `{Binding FirstName}`.

Comment: Cool. I also leave the Path part out for simple properties. So does this mean I could also leave it out when binding something like this: {Binding Person.FirstName}  ???

Comment: Yep, you definitely can. You can even include other attributes, like {Binding Person.FirstName,Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}.

Comment: Ok Matt. I think i MIGHT have found my problem. But let me ask you this before I jump up and down. Will nested property binding work if, say FirstName, is a property that exists in a base class (not directly owned by the Person class)? If not, then this would answer my problem.

Comment: Yep, that's fine. It would have to be a public property, but it doesn't matter where it's defined in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You use this when the object you are binding to is not the same object that is set to the control's DataContext property